# Conditional Formatting Using DT Package in R

Tags: r, shiny, formatting, conditional-formatting, dt

I am trying to replicate Excel's conditional formatting using the DT package in R.

In my example, the football club is selected in the dropdown and their matches appear in the table. I want to highlight each row based on a club's result. The challenge is that the club plays home and away in different matches, so the code needs to cater for this. The row formatting should look like this:

- Green for win — if selected club have scored **more** than their opponents
- Grey for draw — if selected club have scored the **same** as their opponents
- Red for loss — if selected club have scored **less** than their opponents

This is the code I have so far (formatting at the bottom). Clearly it is wrong though, so don't take too much notice of it. All it is doing is highlighting based on a specific number of goals in the `Home.Goals` field.

```r
output$match_cr <- DT::renderDataTable({

        match_cr <- match

        # Find home and away matches involving club selected from dropdown.  
        match_cr <- subset(
            match_cr,
            match_cr$Home.Club == input$club | match_cr$Away.Club == input$club
        )

        if (input$season != "All") {
            match_cr <- subset(
                match_cr,
                Season == input$season
            )
        }

        match_cr

        DT::datatable(match_cr,filter = 'top', options =
                          list(lengthMenu = list(c(-1, 10, 50, 100),
                                            list('All', 10, 50, 100)),
                               pageLength = -1), selection = 'none'

                      ) %>%
            formatStyle(
                          'Home.Goals', target = 'row',
                          backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(2, 1, 0),c('green', 'grey', 'red'))
                      )
    })
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a further column to `match_cr` which indicates whether the selected club won like this:

```
match_cr$win.selected = ifelse(((match_cr$Home.Club == input$club) & (match_cr$Home.Goals > match_cr$Away.Goals)) ||
                               ((match_cr$Away.Club == input$club) & (match_cr$Away.Goals > match_cr$Home.Goals)), 
                               2, 
                               ifelse(match_cr$Home.Goals == match_cr$Away.Goals, 1, 0))
```

You can add it just after your `subset()`. Then you can format the datatable with

```
formatStyle('win.selected', target = 'row',
            backgroundColor = styleEqual(c(2, 1, 0),c('green', 'grey', 'red'))
)
```

Edit: added `match_cr$` to the variable names.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works fine after I removed the extra vertical bar in the first snippet.